# OrientDB create edge issue in batch/script

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have 2 problems with edge creation.

**First**, I'm creating a bunch of vertices and edges with a batch command. Sometimes and edge is created between vertices that havent been created yet *(it depends on the input order, and for now that cannot be controlled)*. Of course Orient server throws an exception instead of failing silently. I couldnt find a way of telling it to skip it or avoid creating the edge. In **Neo4j** you can do:

```
MATCH (a {id:'zz'}),(b {id:'yy'})
CRAETE UNIQUE (a)-[r:REL {'id': 'xx'}]->(b)
```

So if **a** or **b** don't exist, no edge is created.

Is there a way to do something like that? Doing a select before to check for existence of both **a** and **b** is no good because the vertex could be created in the previous batch command, thus not present in the db, so it has to be part of the osql command.

**Second**, related to this issue, I was thinking i could build a script so I could assign the select that looks for both **a** and **b** to a variable.

```
BEGIN
LET source = SELECT FROM V WHERE id = 'zz'
LET target = SELECT FROM V WHERE id = 'yy'
<< some sort of condition based on source != null and target != null? >>
LET edge = CREATE EDGE REL FROM $source TO $target
COMMIT
```

Is it possible to issue the creation command base on a condition on both source and target?. If so, that would solve both issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will be available since v. 2.1.7

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/blob/master/SQL-batch.md#conditional-execution