# OrientDB create edge between two nodes with the same day of year

Tags: orientdb

I'm interested in creating an edge (u,v) between two nodes of the same class in a graph if they share the same day of year and v.year = u.year+1.

Say I have vertices.csv:

```
id,date
A,2014-01-02
B,2015-01-02
C,2016-01-02
D,2013-06-01
E,2014-06-01
F,2016-06-01
```

The edge structure I'd like to see would be this:

```
A --> B --> C
D --> E
F
```

Let's set the vertex class to be "myVertex" and edge class to be "myEdge"?  Is it possible to generate these edges using the SQL interface?

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029088/orientdb-create-edge-issue-in-batch-script), I started trying something like this:

```
BEGIN
LET source = SELECT FROM myVertex
LET target = SELECT from myVertex
LET edge   = CREATE EDGE myEdge
             FROM $source
             TO (SELECT FROM $target WHERE $source.date.format('MM-dd') = $target.date.format('MM-dd')
                 AND $source.date.format('yyyy').asInteger() = $target.date.format('yyyy').asInteger()-1)
COMMIT
```

Unfortunately, this isn't correct. So I got less ambitious and wanted to see if I can create edges just based on matching day-of-year:

```
BEGIN
LET source = SELECT FROM myVertex
LET target = SELECT from myVertex
LET edge   = CREATE EDGE myEdge FROM $source TO (SELECT FROM $target WHERE $source.date.format('MM-dd') = $target.date.format('MM-dd'))
COMMIT
```

Which still has errors... I'm sure it's something pretty simple to an experienced OrientDB user.

I thought about putting together a JavaScript function like [Michela suggested on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782349/create-edges-in-orientdb), but I'd prefer to stick to using the SQL commands as much as possible for now.

Help is greatly appreciated.

---

**Other Stack Overflow References**

- [How to print or log on function javascript OrientDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206122/how-to-print-or-log-on-function-javascript-orientdb)

Comment: It will be easier with a JS server-side function. Let me know if you want some help with that.

Comment: @oleksandr-gubchenko I'm looking into a server-side function for this... Is there a link to some good docs with examples of creating / using functions?  It's been a few years since I've done much Javascript coding... if I'm pulling a record with a date in my script using `V[i].getRecord().field('date')`, would that just return a [javascript date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)?

For now I can run in Studio but down the line I might want to learn how to add & use them in a database from some console interface.

Comment: Official documentation on Javascript API: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Javascript-Driver.html

Comment: Thanks... I'm still having some trouble with this.  The date field that gets returned in the `getRecord().field('date')` command doesn't appear to be a [javascript date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) since I get errors if I try to execute methods like getDate() on it.  How might I go about finding the datatype that I'm dealing with?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with OSQL batch but I think that you can't get what you want.

[image: enter code here]

With whis OSQL batch

```
begin
let a = select @rid, $a1 as toAdd from test let $a1 = (select from test where date.format("MM") == $parent.$current.date.format("MM") and date.format("dd") == $parent.$current.date.format("dd") and @rid<>$parent.$current.@rid and date.format("yyyy") == sum($parent.$current.date.format("yyyy").asInteger(),1))
commit
return $a
```

I got this
[image]

but the problem is that when you create the edge you can not cycle on the table obtained in the previous step.
I think the best solution is to use an JS server-side function.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I can do a server side function but I may not be able to run the server in all environments.  I'm working on java code to do it with a query to just get a table of the edge pairs and then I'll do the create-edge separately.  This example helped alot though as I hadn't experimented before with the sum() function and asInteger() method.  I added a bit less ambitious question focusing on [date manipulations in OSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713423/orientdb-date-manipulation-in-osql-to-find-a-path-with-nodes-on-the-same-day-but).  This helped alot with that. Thanks!