# OrientDB date manipulation in OSQL to find a path with nodes on the same day but different years

Tags: orientdb

I have a graph that is structured like this:

A --> B

A has a Date field.

This is still based on the same problem as in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500535/orientdb-create-edge-between-two-nodes-with-the-same-day-of-year), but this differs in that I'm not concerned with trying to do everything in one OSQL call to create edges.  In this case, I'm only trying to generate a path that looks like:

A1 (date=2014-01-01) ---> B <--- A2 (date=2013-01-01)

And return a table containing just the A1 and A2 id's.

I've started working up a MATCH query that looks like:

```
MATCH {CLASS: A, AS: A1} -edgeTypeA->
  {AS: B} <-edgeTypeA-
  {AS: A2, WHERE: {$matched.A1.Date=$currentMatch.Date}
RETURN A1, B, A2
```

This works but it's only returning matches where basically A1 and A2 are the exact same date (including where A1 and A2 are the same node).

I know I can extract parts of a date field using format()... for example, if I just want a string containing the year I could use $currentMatch.Date.format('yyyy') to get that but I still haven't figured out how to increment that date for the purposes of my query.

Comment: Hi, could be useful a Javascript function? Thx

Comment: Is it the same question that you have already asked here some days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500535/orientdb-create-edge-between-two-nodes-with-the-same-day-of-year ?

Comment: @oleksandr-gubchenko It is still the same problem.  I didn't see Alessandro's reply earlier, I dove into a server-side function, which works but it does require the server to be running, which might not be allowable in some of our environments.  So, I'm working on a java application.  I'm trying to get a bit more generic and just want to get ideas of how exactly one does date manipulation within OSQL.  Most examples I've seen have the date or date-range known a-priori but I care about graph patterns were the path is valid based on relative dates within the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working after seeing [what Alessandro did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500535/orientdb-create-edge-between-two-nodes-with-the-same-day-of-year) in my old question.  I'm adding my solution for archival purposes.  Hopefully it might help others down the line who need to do date manipulation within OSQL queries.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
MATCH {CLASS: A, AS: A1} -edgeTypeA->
    {AS: B} <-edgeTypeA-
    {AS: A2, WHERE: ($matched.A1.Date.format('yyyy').asInteger()=sum($currentMatch.Date.format('yyyy').asInteger(),-1) AND
                     $matched.A1.Date.format('MM-dd')=$currentMatch.Date.format('MM-dd') ) }
RETURN A1,A2
```

and I get the right thing for my data:

```
+----+------+------+
|#   |A1    |A2    |
+----+------+------+
|0   |#49:30|#49:32|
|1   |#55:44|#56:46|
|2   |#53:0 |#53:2 |
|3   |#55:20|#55:22|
|4   |#49:42|#49:44|
|5   |#50:32|#50:34|
+----+------+------+
```

It kind of feels like a lot to have to make the call to [sum()](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html#sum) and [asInteger()](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Methods.html#asinteger) but now I understand it and can work with that.